Is there any way to parameterize the linked service name in a dataset in Azure Synapse Analytics?
I'm new to Azure Synapse Analytics and working with CI/CD pipelines. Currently, I'm exploring how to parameterize pipeline parameters. My current code does not have a template-parameters-definition.json. I've been using syntax like <TriggerName>_properties_typeProperties_scope for triggers and it works fine. Now, I'm curious if it's possible to parameterize the linked service name within a dataset. Below is the dataset definition I've created in Azure Synapse Analytics:
{
    "name": "DATALAKE_FOLDER",
    "properties": {
        "linkedServiceName": {
            "referenceName": "ls_to_storage_account_1",
            "type": "LinkedServiceReference"
        },
        "parameters": {
            "file_system": {
                "type": "string"
            },
            "folder_path": {
                "type": "string"
            }
        },
        "folder": {
            "name": "MyDataset"
        },
        "annotations": [],
        "type": "DelimitedText",
        "typeProperties": {
            "location": {
                "type": "AzureBlobFSLocation",
                "folderPath": {
                    "value": "@dataset().folder_path",
                    "type": "Expression"
                },
                "fileSystem": {
                    "value": "@dataset().file_system",
                    "type": "Expression"
                }
            },
            "columnDelimiter": ",",
            "escapeChar": "\\",
            "firstRowAsHeader": true,
            "quoteChar": "\""
        },
        "schema": []
    }
}

I tried using <DatasetName>_properties_linkedServiceName_referenceName but it does not work. Do I have to use a template-parameters-definition.json?

The storage account name can be dynamic by using parameters in Azure Synapse Analytics. However, not all references can be parameterized. For example, linked service references in datasets and integration runtime references in linked services cannot be parameterized.

please check the solution and let me know if I can help you more.

AFAIK, In Azure Synapse Anayatics We can parameterize the linked services for storage account name. But. we cannot parameterize all the references like linked service name and integration runtime in dataset of Azure Synapse Anayatics.
What we can parameterize in linked service is the storage account name, Server name, database name, Username here is MS document.
If you have any feedback/suggestion related to this, please share it in feedback for Azure Synapse Analytics Services

Does a template-parameters-definition.json help us in this case?
